# How to make constraints work for landscape and portrait (xcode 8.1 / swift3 / storyboard)

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift3, xcode8, nslayoutconstraint

I'm currently trying to make constraint work in both portrait and landscape view.

I started out putting controls to an iPad Pro 9.7 inch portrait view:

[image]

With a hierarchy:

[image]

I had to put two views to force it to center when the user switches to landscape view. I was able to center it but it seemed that scrolling won't work properly. I have to scroll up to see the upper part but once I release, it goes back to that position again.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this using the storyboard? I tried everything like:

-Top space, leading space, trailing space, bottom space, centerX, centerY to - but it became unscrollable

Comment: Have you tried to set constraints on landscape mode in the storyboard ?

Comment: There's a way to separate constraints of landscape and portrait views through storyboard? Can you discuss that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it in **two way**.

1. Using Stack View.
2. Scroll View as your requirement.

   I have added the **image** and all the design are done in **storyboard** so I am giving you `git link`. [Demo Project Link](https://github.com/tiwariammit/ConstraintsTry/tree/master/ContraintsTry)
   Hope it will help for you.
   [image]
   [image]